# Can Websockets be combined with Inter Process Communication?

Tags: java, websocket

I wonder if a server-side application uses Websockets for communicating 
with a Web browser, can this server-side application also use
Inter Process Communication?

The idea is to use the WildFly Web server to execute an application using
Websockets. This application shall also be able to communicate with 
another process. The server-side application shall thus be able to listen
both on events from the Web client and from the other process.
All applications and the other process are implemented in Java.

All help in this area is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? Do you foresee running into some problem?

Comment: Thanks Gaelan and immibis for your answer! The reason for my question was just that I was unsure about this area. I have never used IPC together with Websockets before.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, this should work fine. Neither of these features should affect each other in any way.